# Better UI design for easy booking

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, usability

I am using **[Twitter Bootstrap UI](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap)** for developing screens for my application.

I created the booking / appointment page.

[image]

This page will be used by hospital staffs. They want to quickly fill the data, because they collect all the data from user over phone, meanwhile they fill simultaneously.

> The end user feel this page looks some what hard for them and they
>   want this design to be improved from user experience perspective.

I have no idea on design. User also may want to check the available date & time for the selected doctor in the same page in future.

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you need a designer, you'd be better of contracting a designer through a service like oDesk.

Comment: Whilst there's some interest here, it's off-topic. You'd be better off posting this on [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) where designers, interactions designers and usability architects gather.

Answer (score 4):

you can start with putting together elements that are logically connected to each other.
i did a quick example:
[image: regroup elements for a better understanding of what does what]

then you can also wrap every block in a thin light-gray border and give them a title like "General info", "Submission Date" or whatever will fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I can see some improvements that would help:

1. Group some relevant elements together, in order to be more friendly to the eye.
2. You can use some different background colors to enhance the UI.
3. Use tab indexes to make the navigation from an element to another quicker.
4. You can have some choices pre-filled with the more common ones (the staff will tell you), so they don't have to change everything in every case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using twitter bootstarp, I'm assuming you are using span* and .row right?

You can give a border-bottom and margin 20px/40 to every row. And try to make it like 4 Column, so Responsible person and Categories should be span6 and a border bottom + margin in the parent row.

After that time boxes use span3 for four of them and similarly put border and margin in the bottom part.

Hope that will help you a bit. Although "Antonis Grigoriadis" answere is correct, I'm just starting you on that way :)